# Are there any fonts imitating the correct handwritten forms for Chinese students?

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-characters, fonts

I am hoping to find some resources (hopefully open-source) that allow to type similar to style expected from Chinese students in mainland/Taiwan/Hong Kong schools. If anyone knows Japanese kyōkasho tai fonts as well, they would also be appreciated.

Comment: these have been suggested before and praised by other users, https://www.qt86.com/

Comment: http://www.akuziti.com/cs/xs/

Comment: http://www.diyiziti.com/xingshu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the closest thing to handwritten forms for Chinese-language regulation is in the 楷書 ([regular script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)) style, here are my suggestions:

- Hong Kong: **Free-HK-Kai_4700** https://freehkfonts.opensource.hk/download/ (definitely open source)
- ROC (Taiwan): **TW-Kai-98** https://data.gov.tw/dataset/5961 (unsure if open source)

The ROC (Taiwan) regular script font (**TW-Kai-98**) is a government-mandated standard, so you can be sure of its ability to represent the ROC (Taiwan) standard. The Hong Kong one (**Free-HK-Kai_4700**) is an open-source modification from **TW-Kai-98**, and they have regulated 4700 characters so far (roughly the total number of characters taught in Hong Kong schools).

> EPSON has made a *kyokasho* font quite a while back which is free to download, but I haven't checked the license on its use. You can get the link at http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Japanese.html (CTRL+F **epkyouka**).

---

As an aside, it is not enough to use the fonts to get the correct character forms for each standard - you need to use the correct input method too. Using a **Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)** IME is not appropriate (in an official governmental standard sense) to publish documents adhering to **Chinese (Traditional, Hong Kong)**, or vice-versa, because the suggested characters (Unicode codepoints) that display may be different across the IMEs, although the chance of an actual discrepancy happening is very, very slim.

Comment: Regarding the Epson font, the [homepage](https://www.epson.jp/dl_soft/readme/9296.htm) states that it only can be used in Japan, on the OSes noted, together with the intended product. As such, it is not generally free for use.

Comment: And, TW-Kai-98 is open source. License: https://data.gov.tw/license

Comment: Just to clarify: are the versions at https://github.com/Jiehong/TW-fonts the same as the MOE-specified font? Also, accidentally found Microsoft bundles a "UD Digi KyoKasho" series - probably what's needed for Japanese.